# Wordpress admin running slow

Tags: wordpress

I just finished to produce a website with Wordpress (custom theme, and so on). The thing is, now, the admin is running wery slow (about 40-50 s.) on Chrome. Yeah, it's quite weird, only on Chrome, I get this trouble.

I cleared cookies, cache and everything, without any positive result. I disabled plugins one by one, same. I installed and activated Twenty Eleven theme, nothing changed.

Can this issue come from the database ?

Comment: you don't have this with an other browser? What OS are you on (Windows / Mac). If you only have this on chrome then it can't be database related.

Comment: I had the same problem, but it was across all browsers. The ram of my sever was saturated.
(export your database and import a new one)

Comment: If it occurs only in chrome, this is probably JS related. see if all the scripts are loading including all the libraries (jQuery etc..)